# Best practices for storing key information for encrypted and decrypted a column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, encryption

I have a web service that will be using a SQL Server database to store something that must be encrypted and decrypted. It will periodically need to query the table and get the decrypted form of the data to use in processing.

I have followed [this example here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2431/sql-server-column-level-encryption-example-using-symmetric-keys/) to set up a cert and symmetric key to apply to the column and it works.

What i'm unsure of is what is the best practice for using the name of the key when performing CRUD operations on the table. I am using entity framework, which doesn't naively support encryption and decryption.

So, possibilities I have thought of:

1. Create stored procedures that wrap the CRUD operations. Store the name of the key and cert in the stored procedure itself. Naturally this makes it easy for someone to call this stored procedure to get the decrypted data, although I believe the method will nto work if the DB is moved to another machine, unless you're able to create the root cert for the DB.
   e.g.
2. Similar to #1, but include arguments to the Stored Procedure for key and cert names. Store the key and cert names as hard coded strings in my web service. This isn't that great because the program becomes quite coupled with the name of the cert/key, but I suppose it's already coupled with the definition of the table.

Both of these options work, but from a best practices and security standpoint, there may be better routes here. What are some better alternatives?

example for item 1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDecryptedCustomers
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- reading the data
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;

-- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID 
SELECT Customer_id, CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(Credit_card_number_encrypt)) AS 'Decrypted Credit Card Number'
FROM Customer_data;

 -- Close the symmetric key
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1;
   END 
   GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server 2016, there is new feature called **Always Encryption**  [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/08/27/using-always-encrypted-with-entity-framework-6/)